# Proper way to break pages

Tags: php, html, css, resume, page-break

My PHP script generates variable size text (Resume) and outputs in HTML. What I need is, to break pages using CSS or PHP to mutiple A4 size pages if content longer than 1 page. The problem is, I can't figure out solution because even if I count characters of content it's not possible to calculate height with paddings margins etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: PDF comes to mind. HTML is not made for publishing on print

Comment: @mplungjan I'm generating pdf from html.

Answer (score 2):

CSS offers some facilities for [pages media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html) (ie. printing).

In particular, you probably want to look at `page-break-after`. It depends a bit on your page of course, but a typical usage might look like:

```
.page {
    page-break-after: always;
}

.page.last {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

This will always put a page break after every `.page`, except when it also has the `.last` class (otherwise you'll get an empty page).

Or, you can use more fine-grained control with something like:

```
.section {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This will avoid breaking in the middle of a section.

You can use `@page` set the margins for every page:

```
@page {
    margin: 1cm;
}
```

Be aware that browser settings matter, you can set the margins, print headers, etc. which all influence the result. So the results may vary from machine to machine. There's no way to set these settings in the document.

I also have my resume as a HTML document, and I would **highly** recommend distributing it as PDF (using a PDF printer), not as a webpage, which is too error phrone for such as task (you want it to look correct *100%* of the time, not 95% of the time).

Comment: Yup. Internet Explorer < 9 comes to mind as particularly buggy when dealing with `page-break`. If possible go with PDF.

Comment: I'm generating PDF from html. But still I haven't got answer

Comment: @TT13 What exactly is unclear about my answer? In particular, using `.section { page-break-inside: avoid; }` seems to be what you want? Unless I misunderstood your question...